# Mapping a disc to a square using FG method

Tags: python, math, mesh

**Context**:

I am working with meshes in computational fluid dynamics. I would like to generate a structured mesh around a circle. My plan is to generate a polar mesh (Left mesh in Figure below) then use FG formulas to get the final mesh (Right mesh on Figure below).
I am using FG method from Page 4 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1509/1509.06344.pdf) to map a disc to square . Unfortunately the article doesn't mention how to handle singularities in the formulas. Here are the expressions:

```
x = sgn(uv)/(v*sqrt 2)*sqrt(u**2+v**2-sqrt((u**2+v**2)(u**2+v**2-4u**2v**2)))
```

```
y = sgn(uv)/(u*sqrt 2)*sqrt(u**2+v**2-sqrt((u**2+v**2)(u**2+v**2-4u**2v**2)))
```

[image]

Before programming this, I am struggling with some problems with these formaulas

**Questions**

- Why do these formulae map the following points: `(1,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(-1,0)`, `(-1,-1)`, and `(0,0)` to the point `(0,0)` ?
- How I am supposed to get the intermediate shape between a circle and a square  as shown in the figure below.
- Is it possible to provide an algorithm to get the right mesh from the left one?

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```py
"""Map a circular computational domain with structured mesh around a circle (circular cylinder in 3D) to
Rectangular domain"""

import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, sign, pi, cos, sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def FGsquircle(u, v):
    SMALL = 1e-15
    t0 = u**2+v**2
    t1 = (u**2+v**2)*(u**2+v**2-4*u**2*v**2)
    t2 = u**2+v**2
    t3 = (u**2+v**2)*(u**2+v**2-4*u**2*v**2)

    x = sign(u*v)/(v*sqrt(2.0)+SMALL)*sqrt(t0-sqrt(t1))
    y = sign(u*v)/(u*sqrt(2.0)+SMALL)*sqrt(t2-sqrt(t3))
    return x, y

R0 = 1.0 # radius of the disc
RMAX = 5.0 # the radius of the outer circle in the domain
NT = 360 # num of division in the theta direction
NR = 10 # num of radial divisions
r = [R0+(RMAX-R0)/NR*k for k in range(NR)] # the radii of circles
theta = np.array([2*pi/NT*k for k in range(NT+1)])

u = [r[k]*cos(theta) for k in range(NR)]
v = [r[k]*sin(theta) for k in range(NR)]

u = np.array(u)
v = np.array(v)

x, y = FGsquircle(u, v)
```

I got the following error:

```
utils.py:21: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  x = sign(u*v)/(v*sqrt(2.0)+SMALL)*sqrt(t0-sqrt(t1))
utils.py:22: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  y = sign(u*v)/(u*sqrt(2.0)+SMALL)*sqrt(t2-sqrt(t3))
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://squircular.blogspot.com/2015/09/fg-squircle-mapping.html) which includes code?

Comment: Also, it seems to me that the article assumes the radius is exactly 1. Your multiplication to change the radius to 5 should happen outside of all the other calculations.

Comment: and the points you mention as mapping to `(0,0)` are not covered by the formula; page 2 of the article says `Also note that for the sake of brevity, we have not singled out cases when there are divisions by zero in the mapping equations. For these special cases, just equate x=u, y=v and vice versa when there is an unwanted division by zero in the equations.This usually happens when u=0 or v=0 or both`

Comment: @RossPresser: Yes, I found the article from that website.

Comment: I'm not sure that this problem is really the right one to solve. The derivation of the differential equations for CFD or any other application depends on the coordinate system, and the equations work out differently in important ways depending on the coordinates, because the little volumes from which the equations are derived are different shapes. It seems to me that when you map circles into something else, the equations and boundary conditions will need to be changed too. Or maybe you have already covered that? Maybe ask math.stackexchange.com about it.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do these formulae map the following points: (1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (-1,-1), and (0,0) to the point (0,0) ?

In both expressions, you divide by `u` or `v`, so when one of the two is 0, the expression becomes *undefined* (not zero).

> How I am supposed to get the intermediate shape between a circle and a square as shown in the figure below.

Just map a circle of radius smaller than 1.

> Is it possible to provide an algorithm to get the right mesh from the left one?

You'll just need to transform the mesh points. The cells can remain the same.

---

Example code:

```py
from numpy import sqrt, sign
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(x):
    u, v = x
    alpha = sqrt(
        u ** 2
        + v ** 2
        - sqrt((u ** 2 + v ** 2) * (u ** 2 + v ** 2 - 4 * u ** 2 * v ** 2))
    )
    return numpy.array(
        [sign(u * v) / (v * sqrt(2)) * alpha, sign(u * v) / (u * sqrt(2)) * alpha]
    )


for r in numpy.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10):
    theta = numpy.linspace(0.0, 2 * numpy.pi, 1000, endpoint=True)
    uv = r * numpy.array([numpy.cos(theta), numpy.sin(theta)])
    xy = f(uv)

    plt.plot(xy[0], xy[1], "-")

plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

[image]